# Timeless JWT token for frontend app to use with Laravel API

Tags: laravel, jwt, authorization, access-token

I'm developing Laravel API for frontend React app and I need to authorize forever a system user for this app. For authorization I'm using JWT ( https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ ).

To reach this goal I did:

1. Created a user for frontend:

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
   'email' => '2f44dc847e9c0395@9f5b2d7aaa76a6d3.app',
   'password' => Hash::make('3b59e893657e'),
   'role' => 'app'
]);
```

2. Created a login method that makes 50-year token for this user:

```
public function login(): JsonResponse
{
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

    if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
       return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }

    // 50-year token for app system user
    if (auth()->user()->role === 'app') {
       if (! $token = auth()->setTTL(26280000)->attempt($credentials)) {
           return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
       }
    }

    return $this->respondWithToken($token);
}
```

3. Used this method via swagger documentation page for get token.
4. Saved token in .env of my frontend app
5. Using it as authorization header.

**But sometimes (about once a month) this token fails and I need to generate a new one.**

I also plan to connect a second API to my front-end project and log in using the same token.

Is it possible to somehow statically set a token, for example, through an env file and use it?
Or maybe there is some other way to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I hade the same issue but this solution I got online helped me. 

 https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/2095#issuecomment-797293274

Comment: @Kwenziwa Lizwi Khanyile thank you! Finally I made a custom token for current user and stored it as a string in .env, but your solution is maybe better.